# Execute jquery animate only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following function:

```
$('.link1').click(function(){
    $("#div2").slideUp(function(){$("#div1").slideToggle();});
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '600px'}, 800);
});
```

It toggles a div and scroll the page down. The problem is that everytime the user toggles the page scroll down again...how could I run this animate function only at first click?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a flag or set a data attribute to make sure the scrolling animation only occurs on the first click.

```
var flag=true;

$('.link1').click(function(){
    $("#div2").slideUp(function(){$("#div1").slideToggle();});
    if (flag) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '600px'}, 800);
        flag = false;
    }
});
```

I'm guessing `#div2` should still toggle, but that it just should'nt scroll on every click?

Comment: @Archer - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @j08691 - If the OP wrote the question right, the point is'nt to just run the click function once, the point is to toggle the div on every click, but to only do the scrolling on the first click, which makes most of the answers wrong!

Comment: @adeneo is it really such a leap of thought to only put one of the statements into a `one`? Answers on SO are not meant to be copy-paste fixes, merely guidance.

Comment: But `.one()` will not work! There will be no toggling if the click function only executes once, so it does'nt matter if it's not copy/paste, it's simply the wrong answer with the wrong method, at least it is if you read the question, stating that the OP does not wish to have the animated scroll effect everytime the element toggles, and with most of the answers there will be no toggle at all? Also the click handler is attached to a class, and `one` will again only execute once, so if there are several elements with the same class, same problem?

Comment: @j08691 "how could I run this animate function only at first click?" seems perfectly clear to me that he just wants the scroll to run 1st time.  The rest needs to run every time.  Assumptions were made and incorrect code was posted.  This answer is currently the only correct one.

Comment: I just used the .one function from Mattheww as a new function with the animate inside. it worked.

Comment: That will work as well, but now you have to event handlers for the same event and the same element, not that it matters. The answer you accepted is wrong the way it stands, but then again, who cares?

Comment: @user1541940 You worded the question wrong then as you said you only wanted the animate function to run once.  Using `.one` also means the slideUp function only runs once, which is not what you said.

Comment: adeneo you were right...I just tested with your code and it worked better. Sorry guys, my bad! I'm pretty new to jquery and I'm trying to learn it.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery .one() http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$('.link1').one( 'click', function(){
    $("#div2").slideUp(function(){$("#div1").slideToggle();});
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '600px'}, 800);
});
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Honestly I haven't needed a handler to execute only once, but it's interesting that jQuery includes this method.

Comment: I'm guessing the point is to avoid the scrolling on subsequent clicks, and not run the entire click function only once ?

Comment: @adeneo Knowing that he wants that slidetoggle to live more than once, using a flag makes sense indeed. :)

Answer (score 1):

use the `.one` function to bind an event that fires only once.

```
$('.link1').one('click', function(){
    $("#div2").slideUp(function(){$("#div1").slideToggle();});
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '600px'}, 800);
});
```

Comment: this or `unbind('click')` would be the best options.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with JQuery.

> **The CSS used:**

```
.cpos {
    position: relative;
    top: -1.65em;
    left: 1.8em;
}
```

> **The JQuery used:**

```
var p=null; /* Initialize variable p. */
p=$("b").detach(); /* Detach every possible <b>b</b>-tags. */
var p=$("<b>Console loaded!</b>").addClass("cpos"); /* Do anything, like adding class. */
p.appendTo("#container"); /* Append new data to the anchor container. */
```

Maybe you could use this for reference when animating. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could unbind that click handler at the end of the handler so that it never triggers again:

```
$('.link1').off('click');
```

Comment: be aware that `off` only works for handlers that were bound by `on`, which is not the case in the OP's snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Use a flag

```
var noRun = 0
$('.link1').click(function(){
    if(noRun==1) {
      return
     }
     noRun = 1  
    $("#div2").slideUp(function(){$("#div1").slideToggle();});
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '600px'}, 800);
});
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer, so why the down-vote?

Answer (score -1):

You can save a simple "token" to check if is the first time that click is fired in this way:

```
$('.link1').click(function(){ 
    if(!$(this).data('isFirstTime')) {
        $("#div2").slideUp(function(){$("#div1").slideToggle();}); 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '600px'}, 800); 
        $(this).data('isFirstTime', true);
    }
});
```

This should prevent further click

Answer (score -1):

This should do it

```
(function(){
    var first=true;
    $('.link1').click(function(){
        if (first){
            first=false;
            $("#div2").slideUp(function(){$("#div1").slideToggle();});
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '600px'}, 800);
        }
    });
})();
```