# How to slide to top of panel-heading in bootstrap collapse for nested panel-groups too

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/howovu/1/

*http://jsbin.com/howovu/1/edit*

### When testing: Make the viewport shorter than the content.

This slides to top of the clicked panel-heading based on the following jQuery:

```
// slide to top of the clicked panel -- does not work with nested accordions
    $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
        var panel = $(this).find('.in');
       $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: panel.offset().top + (-60)
       }, 500);
    });
```

*I believe this fixes it, still testing:*

```
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        var panel = $(this).find('.in');
       $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: panel.offset().top + (-60)
       }, 500);
      e.stopPropagation(); //added
    });
```

But when you click on a nested .panel-group (see the example == HAS nested), it bounces and then bounces back to a parent. I tried .next (instead of .find) but that didn't work. My jQuery chops are somewhat crappified.

I can't use an ID on the jQuery, it must work with all .panel-group.

Thanks ahead of time if anyone can help with this.

### Goal: Click the top of the current panel-heading and slide to the top of that panel-heading even if it's nested.

Tried: .children().find('.in') -- did the same thing - trying other stuff too

Comment: i don't understand the question: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Updated question: Goal: Click the top of the current panel-heading and slide to the top of that panel-heading even if it's nested.

Comment: please add that this needs to be tested on a smaller screen or mobile... i for one have a 27" monitor and had no idea what you were talking about until i narrowed down the window to something very small...

Comment: Thanks. But I did put that on in the first part of the question "make the viewport shorter than the content"

Comment: I made it bigger now

Comment: i honestly thought that was one of your goals, maybe you want to add "When testing this, make sure the viewport is shorter than the content" or something around those lines...

Comment: Thank you! I added as you suggested.

Comment: thank you, i voted up! ;) trying to see what this could be caused by, though this might be a little too complicated for my js knowledge :) maybe someone else will be able to help...

Comment: you want to have [Collapsible Group Item #3 == HAS NESTED ] on top even when [Nested 3] is clicked?

Comment: I want to have the top panel of that nested to be on top, I want it to go to the top of the parent or the child depending on whether it's nested or not

Comment: I got it to work in a bizarre way: http://jsbin.com/moyomu/2/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a flag for this, and set it to `false` once the animation completes, but set it again to true once you clicked the panel. Slightly cumbersome, but does the trick:

```
var flag;
$('.panel-group').click(function(){
  flag = true;
});
$('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    var panel = $(this).find('.in');
    if (flag) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: panel.offset().top -60
      }, 500);
      flag = false;
    }
});
```

Updated your demo: http://jsbin.com/zozavefibuqa/1

Credit / source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11691120/2037924

**EDIT**: I removed the first `var flag = true;` statement as it was unnecessary, turned it into `var flag;` to simply declare the variable. Demo URL updated.

Comment: Thank you, what do you think of this: http://jsbin.com/qutika/1/ -- added stopPropagation and it appears to work as intended.

Comment: Yours works more smoothily and so thank you very much!

Comment: note that i removed the first `var flag = true;` statement as it was unnecessary, turned it into `var flag;` to simply declare the variable. Demo URL updated.

Comment: I'd up this again if I could. Thank you this one works even better.